# UITableViewCell didSelectRowAt: not getting called when press on UIButton area in cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have added `UIButton`(for some functionality requirement in project.) with checkbox image. Checkbox image select and unselect working proper on `UITableViewCell` tap but if I tap cell on checkbox button area button image isn't changing. I mean `didSelectRowAt` method isn't calling.[image]

Comment: Then how do you consider that select and unselect is working proper unless you can see it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. I have checked that UIButton's `UserInteraction` ignores UITableViewCell's tap.

So I have just added below line in my code. And cell tap working good.

```
cell.btnCheck.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: What is the purpose of adding a UIButton then ? Or to put it better - how would you achieve functionality in button event ?

Comment: @Nitish Previous requirement was to click on only UIButton, But now requirement is to click on UITableviewCell.